# Unable to use Unicode's FontAwesome encoding in such a way as &#xf283 "data-xxx="

Tags: html, web-applications, unicode, font-awesome

First of all, I am sorry, my English is not good. I use the way of machine translation.

HTML：

```
<li class="payrecord-col" data-tags="&#xf283;">
   ...
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.payrecord-row .payrecord-col:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome' !important;
  font-style: normal;
  content: attr(data-tags);
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

In this case, I found that the rendered page does not display the FontAwesome icon.

Like this question would like to ask your friends if there is a solution?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If there is other way to use fontawsome, but I use it really differently, in HTML:

include it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

than in where you want to use

```
<li><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i></li>
```

Comment: and you can choose the icon [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)